# Number theory: $(a + b)^p ≡ a^p + b^p\pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm just a little stuck on this problem. I think the solution must incorporate something like Fermat's theorem, but I'm struggling with getting it exactly correct.

Show that if $p$ is a prime number and $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, then

$$(a + b)^p \equiv a^p + b^p \pmod{p}$$

Comment: Using Fermat's little theorem this is trivial, since both sides become $a+b$. However, that's shooting mosquitoes with a cannon.

Comment: Look at the prime rows of Pascal's triangle, what do you notice about the *interior* entries.

Comment: Use binomial theorem.  $(a + b)^p = \sum {p \choose k}a^kb^{p-k}$.  Prove $p|{p \choose k}$ for all $1<k < p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the congruence
$$(a+b)^p=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}a^{p-k}b^{k}\equiv a^{p}+b^{p}\pmod p$$

This is clear by the fact that $p$ divides all the binomial coefficients for $1\leq k\leq p-1$. Hence all multiples of these binomial coefficients, being some multiple of $p$ drop out of the congruence.

To see this:
$$\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}=\frac{p(p-1)\dotsm(p-k)}{(p-k)!}$$
Now $p-k<p$, and so $p$ being prime can share no factors with $(p-k)!$. Hence $p$ doesn't divide the denominator; but $\binom{p}{k}\in\Bbb{N}$, and $p$ divides the numerator, so $p\mid\binom{p}{k}$ for $1\leq k\leq p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Use the binomial theorem and have a look at the binomial coefficients.